# Process.Start not function

Tags: vb.net

How to make it work?

For when I press the button my game starts with the ip already entered.

My code:

```
 Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim startInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(My.Settings.SaveFiveM)
        startInfo.Arguments = "+connect " & My.Settings.SaveIp
        Process.Start(startInfo)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Process.Start(My.Settings.SaveDiscord)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Process.Start("http://www.website.net/")
    End Sub
End Class
```

But the game starts but without the ip

In my form2 I have a textbox with the ip to put, and that's what I have information "My.Settings.SaveIp"

Thank you

Sorry for my english i'm french

Comment: Your question boils down to how to get a `String` from one form in another. That's it. That's something you can look up on the web.

Comment: the question is not very clear. If you have difficulty with English, please ask someone to help you translate, or even try an an automated translation to help with some of it. I _think_ you want to get some data which is in Form2 and show it in Form1. If so, it's probably quite a simple solution. But I'm not sure. Maybe you can include a picture to help our understanding.

Comment: I'm sorry for my english. Yes, here is my problem in simple. This is my code     Dim startInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(My.Settings.SaveFiveM)
    startInfo.Arguments = "+connect 000.000.000.00:00000"
    Process.Start(startInfo).                                                                                 And How to make the IP editable with a 'My.Settings.NAME"

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code to it.

Comment: IvanH it's edit

Comment: so you want the user to enter the IP address, and use that to connect, instead of getting the IP from the settings?

Answer (score 0):

To get the directory of a file, just use a `FolderBrowserDialog`.

In your list of controls, double-click `FolderBrowserDialog` and the should create one called `FolderBrowserDialog1`

you can then adapt this code for your own buttons and variable names

```
Dim DiscordPath As String


Private Sub btnSetDiscordDirectory_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSetDiscordDirectory.Click
    Dim folderSearchResult As DialogResult = FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog
    If Not folderSearchResult = DialogResult.Cancel Then
        DiscordPath = IO.Path.Combine(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "Discord.exe")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not exactly that. The place of the file is to the user of the insert, and with this one can launch the file. I give you an example to better understand. zupimages.net/up/18/18/ejii.png